How to bleed air from Force brand heating system with no obvious drain hookup
I have a Force brand boiler in the basement connected to a multi-zone baseboard system.  I hear gurgling sounds in a number of the zones, and one zone doesn't reliabily heat (as of a few days ago).  So I have decided to bleed the air from my system.  Unfortunately, my system doesn't look like a lot of the ones I've seen youtube how-to videos.  In particular, I don't see drain hose connection on the return-side of my boiler.
On the output side, I see the hot water pipe come out of the boiler and the go to the wall where it splits in to 7 zones, each with a automatic switch (connected to the room thermostat), a shut-off valve below the automatic switch and a hose-connection in between these two.

On the boiler itself, I see the return pipe (black), but there is no hose connection on it.

The return pipe is black and goes straight up to the ceiling.

In the ceiling, it seems to connect to the various zone return pipes.

But the root of my problem is that I don't see a hose connection on the return side, so I don't know how to drain the air/water from it.  Does this kind of system bleed out a different way?  The boiler's part number is Force 08N-RHG1
For additional information, here are some photos of other parts of the system:

I believe this is the feeder valve where fresh water can be pushed in to the system.  It connects to the output pipe in between the boiler and where the various zones split off to the automatic zone switches.


Contraption on the boiler where the new hot water leaves to go to the zone splitters.


Contraption on the bottom of the boiler where the old water returns.


PRessure gauge on the boiler




Since air rises in water, the most effective way to bleed the system is at the baseboard convector. There are numerous tutorials, e.g., https://inspectapedia.com/heat/Air_Bleeder_Valves.php or https://www.1tomplumber.com/how-bleed-baseboard-radiators/

I have a procedure for you that I've used with good results on a system like this, but first please EDIT to add a photo of your supply water pressure reducer / regulator on the left side of the boiler near the transformer on the wall. It's in shadow so I can't make it out. Also say if you have a working system pressure gauge or not.

@DrMoishePippik as far as I can tell, our baseboards don't have bleeder valves.  At least, the one in the bedroom at issue does not. I checked both ends (there is a single long baseboard there) and neither end has a bleeder valve.

@MTA I added some more photos - let me know if that is sufficient

Check other convectors, which might be in series with the bedroom.

@DrMoishePippik That zone only supplies that one bedroom (and it's bathroom, which has a small baseboard which also has no apparent bleeder).

You need a short garden hose about long enough to reach the floor from any of the 7 garden hose spigots on your 7 zones. An old washing machine supply hose would be ideal.
You also need a bucket, minimum 5 gallons.
Turn the boiler off using the switch in the red cover plate.
Close all 7 manual ball valves for the 7 zones.
Select a zone that you're going to de-air, connect a garden hose to its spigot and put the other end in the bucket. Once we start, you always want the free end of the hose to remain under water to prevent air from entering the hose and plumbing.
Now manually open the electric zone valve for that zone by pushing the lever on top of the zone valve body across its travel till it reaches a notch, and engage the lever in the notch to hold it in place. You need to use adequate force to move the lever, and it will move slowly because of gearing.
Open the water supply's ball valve above the backflow preventer and leave it open for the duration. You may get some flow if the system has lost any water.
Take note of the gauge pressure when flow stops, if there is any flow.
Now open the spigot that the hose is attached to. Water flows from your water supply regulator through the pump, through the boiler, past the expansion tank and to the upstairs, then returns to the basement through one of 7 zones, through the open electric zone valve and spigot into the bucket.
The goal is to get rapid flow of water that will carry air along at a good enough pace that the bubbles will be forced from the upper levels down into the basement, against their natural tendency to rise. You need to watch the water accumulating in the bucket and look for bubbles, which will be obvious when they appear.
You may need to open the spigot fully to get enough flow. If the flow still seems inadequate to force bubbles down the pipe into the basement, you'll need to override the water supply's pressure regulator by pulling that lever on the regulator. Use your judgment to decide how much to pull it from its resting angle, possibly all the way to straight. That will increase the pressure and flow. But use caution: keep an eye on your pressure gauge and do not allow the system pressure to go higher than about 25 psi or your pressure release may dump water on the floor.
Important: Never increase pressure manually unless a spigot is open. That means that when your bubbles appear and it's time to stop, put the pressure lever back to its original position, THEN close the spigot.
If one bucket of water doesn't give you bubbles, go for another bucket.
When that zone is done, close the electric zone valve by releasing the lever from the notch and move on to the next zone.
When you're completely done, open all 7 zone ball valves, let the pressure return to final equilibrium and turn off the water supply valve, and turn the power back on.
Note that adding new water to a sealed heating system tends to promote rust, though at this point you have little choice. If you find that you have to de-air the system frequently, you may benefit by installing bleeders upstairs.

I'm a little confused, because with the hose attached to the spigot under the auto-switch, wouldn't water have to flow in reverse to go upstairs and then down through the auto-switch and out the pipe?  Normally water is going up that pipe from the boiler, but to drain from there, it would be going in reverse.  And since the filler source is on that side of the boiler, the new water is going to have to go through the boiler and out the other end - through the return-pipe and upstairs that way?  Or am I misunderstanding things?

@Doug
You've got it right, and flushing direction doesn't matter, as long as the bubbles move. P.S., I think you've assumed a normal flow direction opposite what it actually is; isn't the pipe at the right rear of the boiler hotter than the pipe just above the pump? I think all the zone valves are in the return to the boiler, not the hot supply. Either way, flushing works fine the way I suggest. You can also look for an arrow for the direction of flow that's cast into the body of the pump opposite the motor. You may need a mirror to see it.

Wait - you think the new hot water leaves via the black pipe that comes out on the bottom of the boiler, and the old not-as-hot water returns in the copper pipe through each of the zone valves and then enters the boiler via the copper pipe higher up? I guess I assumed that you turned off a zone at the input side, not the return side, and I had read somewhere that cold water typically entered at the bottom and hot water left at the top.

@Doug None of this matters for de-airing. The black pipe that enters the boiler near the bottom is a gas pipe. The red Grundfos pump in the middle of the right side is where the cooled-off water returns. The pipe coming out the top of the boiler in the right rear is where the hot water leaves, then turns and passes the expansion tank. The other pipe that left a mess on the floor is the safety pressure release. Boiler manufacturers typically put the pump on the inlet to keep the pump cooler and prolong its life. Go feel the pipes, you'll see. And look for the flow direction arrow on the pump.

Ah - now I do feel silly.  Knowing which pipes were which is helpful.  I followed your instructions and the heat's back on.  Thanks!

@Doug Glad it worked out. Stay warm!
